# Add a Role for myself discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to do a `setup` command so I can create a role and give it to myself via a command. The role is created but I cannot give myself the role. I always get an error code after the role was created.

My Code:

```js
            case 'setup':

                if(!message.author.id == '416940852291045376') return message.channel.send('Youre not me') 

                message.guild.roles.create({
                    name: 'Bot dev',
                    color: '#0080FF',
                    permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR'
                })
                .catch(console.error);
            
            
                let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Bot dev")
                let member = message.member
            
                member.roles.add(role)
```

The error code i'm getting:

```js
C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:110
        throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'roles', 'Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes');
              ^

TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
```

Comment: Log `role`, what do you get? I think it's `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RoleManager#create()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) returns a promise with the newly created role, you must await it or resolve it before searching for the role.

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
   name: 'Bot dev',
   color: '#0080FF',
   permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR'
})
.then(role => {
    const { member } = message;
    member.roles.add(role);
})
.catch(console.error);
```